# What will the correct value of spin quantum number for last electron of Na+ ion?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, orbitals, atomic-structure

Electronic configuration of $Na^+$ ion is $1s^2,2s^2,2p^6,3s^0$.

I have noticed usually , we take spin quantum number as +1/2 first & then -1/2.

So , like for the above Q:It is for first 3e=+1/2 & last 3 = -1/2.

But , according to Hunds rule in my textbook. There are 2 ways spin quantum number is given I.e for N atom as example:

[image]

Electronic configuration of N = $1s^2,2s^2,2p^3$

For the last 3 electrons , either it is +1/2 or -1/2 as starting for the  first 3 electrons.

So , I am having difficulty in understanding whether also for Na+ ions , we can start the order of spin in any way I.e it could be +1/2 or -1/2 for starting ?

I can’t share an image as I have less than 15 reputation. I can share if the image u can help me with getting 15 reputation to share the image & after some time. You can decide if you want to continue the upvote or remove it.

Comment: Yes, both values i.e. positive and negative are valid for starting to fill an orbital.

Comment: But in my textbook , when I was practicing Q. It was an MCQ based Q & only 1 option was correct form it i.e one with -1/2. Why is that ?

Comment: Can you also share the image of the question you refer to?

Comment: Image is not loading. It is getting failed again & again. I’ll share as this problem resolves. Must be internet connection. I also had difficulty in posting this Q earlier.

Comment: Do you know which rule this represent to & why is this true ? @NisargBhavsar

Comment: Maybe the question was assuming you to follow the general convention of filling the +1/2 electrons first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132868/discussion-between-nisarg-bhavsar-and-goku777).